# Бит имейдж или канва? Что лучше?

Tags: delphi

Я пишу курсовую, мне нужно нарисовать график функции.
Но эта функция в цикле и мне нужно, чтоб она выводила каждое значение в точку на графике.Есть какие-нибудь мысли? Или сделать через tchar, но как? Пробовал так:

```
Function y1(x:real):real;    
   begin    
      y1:=cos(x)-(4*x)+1;
   end;

Function y2(x:real):real;    
   begin    
      y2:=-sin(x)-4;
   end;

Function y3(x:real):real;    
   begin
      y3:=-cos(x);
   end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);    
   begin    
      begin    
         a1:=StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
         b1:=StrToFloat(Edit5.Text);
         d:=StrToFloat(Edit4.Text);
         begin
           if (abs(y1(a1)*y3(b1))>d)then
              w:=a1 else w:=b1;
         end;
         x:=w-(y1(w)/y2(w));
         while (abs(y1(w))<d) do
           w:=x;
      end;
      xr1:=x;            
      Label1.Caption:='метод касательных='+FloatToStr(xr1);    
   end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте TChart, не стоит усложнять себе задание. Если TChart не хватает, найдите полную версию TChart PRO ( к сожалению она платная :). 

 Update 1:

```
 for k:=0 to 20 do
  Chart1.SeriesList[0].AddXY(k, cos(k*pi/5),' ', clRed);
```

Пример рисования графика в TChart. [Пример взят отсюда.](http://it.kgsu.ru/DelAdd/deladd19.html)

Comment: а как ее связать с  результатом?

Comment: @electrovolk Для уточняющих вопросов правильно использовать комментарии.

Answer (score 0):

Самый удобный и быстрый способ работы - напрямую с TBitmap. Выдерживает обработку более чем 9000*9000 точек (32 бита). При этом работает очень быстро.

Изображение строится в памяти, затем переносится на Canvas с помощью одной из множества функций, начиная с ассемблерных вставок и заканчивая `Canvas.Draw(x, y, Bitmap);`

Приходилось когда-то рисовать в рамках учебной программы: карты, 3D-примитивы и т.п.